# How to split string based on pre-defined values from Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I want to split a string based on an array that I define as a constant at the start:

```
class Query
  OPERATOR = [':','=','<','>','<=','>=']
  def initialize(params)
    #Here i want to split given params if it contains any
    #of the operators from OPERATOR     
  end
end

Query.new(["Status<=xyz","Org=abc"])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: When asking about a problem with your code it's helpful if you provide the sample input and expected output. If we build our own input and output expectations we won't necessarily match the criteria you have. Read "[mcve]". Also, while you provide a shell, you don't show any attempt to solve the problem. It's really important you show us what you tried and explain why it didn't work. Failing to do that makes it look like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OPERATOR = ['<=','=>',':','=','<','>']

r = /\s*#{ Regexp.union(OPERATOR) }\s*/
  #=> /\s*(?-mix:<=|=>|:|=|<|>)\s*/

str = "Now: is the =time for all <= to =>"

str.split(r)
  #=> ["Now", "is the", "time for all", "to"]
```

Note that I reordered the elements of `OPERATOR` so that `'<='` and `'=>'` (each comprised of two strings of length one in the array) are at the beginning. If that is not done,

```
OPERATOR = [':','=','<','>','<=','>=']
r = /\s*#{ Regexp.union(OPERATOR) }\s*/
  #=> /\s*(?-mix::|=|<|>|<=|>=)\s*/ 
str.split(r)
  #=> ["Now", "is the", "time for all", "", "to"] 

str.split(r)
```

See [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

Comment: Thanks that works but with one small problem. See output below. Seems like where it encounters <= or >= it actually adds an empty newline.
Now
 is the 
time for all 

 to

Comment: Thanks. It does still show white spaces but i am sure i will figure that out.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to remove the spaces. I fixed it so that it would.

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thanks